# Why does Actionscript displays different values for modulus of large values?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Using Flash CS4 with Actionscript 3 I type the following:

```
 trace(Math.pow(97,83) % 205);
```

Which results in 86. However if I type in Wolfram-Alpha:

```
 97^83 mod 205
```

I get 13 which is the right answer. Why is actionscript displaying the wrong value?

Thanks,
Y_Y

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to float point precision of the Number type.  Flash only uses 64 bits to represent the result of Math.pow(97,83) of which 53 are used to describe the mantissa portion of the floating point number.  With 53 bits, you can only get about 15-16 digits of precision on a number before you need to round it.  Since Math.pow(97,83) is a number roughly 164 digits long, Flash keeps an approximation of the form 7.98093813043768e+164

This is not the exact value of Math.pow(97,83) due to the loss of precision and thus will yield bad results when calculating a mod.

Wolfram-Alpha probably uses a specialized library for calculating large numbers without loss of precision.  I am not aware of any such libraries for Actionscript 3 but google may help there ;)

Comment: Googling for "as3 biginteger" will yield some relevant results.

Comment: I googled as3 biginteger and I came across as3crypto :| its kinda hard to understand how it works because I do:
     var a:BigInteger = new BigInteger("50", 10);
     trace(a.toString(10));
And the answer is 280. Any other library I could use?

Answer (score 2):

Because the result of `97^83` is way too large to be calculated correctly in AS3.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Answer (score 1):

While you have a correct answer by @Godfather up there, here are my 5 cents.

```
var test:String = "";

// a binary number with bit 53 up
test += "10000000"; // 8
test += "00000000"; // 16
test += "00000000"; // 24
test += "00000000"; // 32
test += "00000000"; // 40
test += "00000000"; // 48
test += "00000";    // 53

trace("test", test);
trace(parseInt(test, 2).toString(2) == test); // true

test += "1"; // bit 0 and 54 up, the rest -- down

var chck:String = parseInt(test, 2).toString(2);
trace("test", test);
trace("chck", chck);
trace(chck == test); // false
```

This yields:

```
test 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
true
test 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
chck 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
false
```

So, you can use integers up to

```
dec: 9007199254740991
hex: 1FFFFFFFFFFFFF
bin: 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Here is another sample:

```
trace(parseFloat("9007199254740993") == parseFloat("9007199254740992"));
// output: true
```

Comment: What's the logic behind doing,  trace(chck == test); ?? Can you please throw some light. I am curious but didnot understand.

Comment: `test` is just a string with 0 and 1 characters in it. `parseInt()` is used to convert the string `test` to a Number. What I do is converting `test` to number and *back to string*. The result of conversion is saved to `chck`. Then, I compare the results of converting test back and forth. The results do not match, hence we have hit the limit for whole part of the number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)... What is your suggestion? Should I split up the integers for me to be able to do the pow?

Comment: I suggest that you should look at java biginteger library. Either try to find a ported as3 version, or port it yourself (porting java code to as3 is usually not a big problem).